# Programming pattern for components that are toggleable at runtime

Tags: c++, performance, design-patterns, components

I'm wondering if there is some kind of logical programming pattern or structure that I should be using if sometimes during runtime a component should be used and other times not. The obvious simple solution is to just use if-else statements everywhere. I'm trying to avoid littering my code with if-else statements since once the component is toggled on, it will more than likely be on for a while and I wonder if its worth it to recheck if the same component is active all over the place when the answer will most likely not have changed between checks.

Thanks

A brief example of what I'm trying to avoid

```
class MainClass
{
public:
    // constructors, destructors, etc

private:
    ComponentClass m_TogglableComponent;
}

// somewhere else in the codebase
if (m_TogglableComponent.IsActive())
{
    // do stuff
}

// somewhere totally different in the codebase
if (m_TogglableComponent.IsActive())
{
    // do some different stuff
}
```

Comment: Maybe [Making a Plugin System](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/48TbqMoL/) can get you started.

Comment: That link is about dlls, which seems overkill for this simple case (with more details it might turn out to be suitable)

Comment: For all intents and purposes I suppose you could think of the togglable component as a file that could get corrupted and close at some undetermined time. You toggle it on with Open and toggle it off with Close, but there's also the scenario where the file dies in middle of runtime and so it becomes closed without an explicit call to Close. How do you handle doing the writing? Do you wrap each write call in a check to see if the file is open? Do you just fail the write silently? Do you throw an error? Should this unexpected close be its own separate type of state that should be checked against?

Comment: Is `m_TogglableComponent` toggled only by means of some public methods of `MainClass`?

Comment: No the togglable component can also be toggled by internal events like exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're headed towards a feature toggle. This is a common occurrence when there's a piece of functionality that you need to be able to toggle on or off at run time. The key piece of insight with this approach is to use polymorphism instead of if/else statements, leveraging object oriented practices.

Martin Fowler details an approach here, as well as his rationale: http://martinfowler.com/articles/feature-toggles.html

But for a quick answer, instead of having state in your ComponentClass that tells observers whether it's active or not, you'll want to make a base class, AbstractComponentClass, and two base classes ActiveComponentClass and InactiveComponentClass. Bear in mind that m_TogglableComponent is currently an automatic member, and you'll need to make it a pointer under this new setup.

AbstractComponentClass will define pure virtual methods that both need to implement. In ActiveComponentClass you will put your normal functionality, as if it were enabled. In InactiveComponentClass you do as little as possible, enough to make the component invisible as far as MainClass is concerned. Void functions will do nothing and functions return values will return neutral values.

The last step is creating an instance of one of these two classes. This is where you bring in dependency injection. In your constructor to MainClass, you'll take a pointer of type AbstractComponentClass. From there on it doesn't care if it's Active or Inactive, it just calls the virtual functions. Whoever owns or controls MainClass is the one that *injects* the kind that you want, either active or inactive, which could be read by configuration or however else your system decides when to toggle.

If you need to change the behaviour at run time, you'll also need a setter method that takes another AbstractComponentClass pointer and replaces the one from the constructor.